# What kind of radical makes sense?

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, ideals

I have the following exercise: Find the radical of the subring $S\subset M_n(\mathbb{C})$, where $S$ consists of upper triangular matrices.

Unfortunately it is not specified what kind of radical is ment. What makes the most sense here? The Jacobson radical?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Jacobson radical, most likely. It is the set of strictly upper triangular matrices.

Work to confirm this using whatever characterizations of the Jacobson radical that you know.

Comment: Here is a relevant question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2609491/29335

Comment: Thanks! I could verify this using the following characterization: $J(S)=\{x\in S\mid 1-xy\in S^\times\forall y\in S\}$.

Comment: @mathstackuser Yes: it is elementary to see that the determinant of such a matrix is nonzero.